# To calculate Moving/Rolling back Weekly (7 days) Sum:

Tags: unix, awk

Please help to calculate `Moving/Rolling back Weekly Sum of Amount($4)`  based on `Distributor wise ($2) and Rolling Date wise`.

Want to set vaiable like

```
RollingStartDate ==01/05/2015 and RollingInterval==7 and  RollingEndDate ==08/05/2015
```

For Example :

```
1st May 2015 Rolling 7 Days data set would be from 01/05/2015 to 25/04/2015
2nd May 2015 Rolling 7 Days data set would be from 02/05/2015 to 26/04/2015
....................................................................
7th May 2015 Rolling 7 Days data set would be from 07/05/2015 to 01/05/2015
8th May 2015 Rolling 7 Days data set would be from 08/05/2015 to 02/05/2015
```

Input.csv

```
Des,Date,Distributor,Amount,Loc
aaa,25/04/2015,abc123,25,bbb
aaa,25/04/2015,xyz456,75,bbb
aaa,26/04/2015,xyz456,50,bbb
aaa,27/04/2015,abc123,250,bbb
aaa,27/04/2015,abc123,100,bbb
aaa,29/04/2015,xyz456,50,bbb
aaa,30/04/2015,abc123,25,bbb
aaa,01/05/2015,xyz456,75,bbb
aaa,01/05/2015,abc123,50,bbb
aaa,02/05/2015,abc123,25,bbb
aaa,02/05/2015,xyz456,75,bbb
aaa,04/05/2015,abc123,30,bbb
aaa,04/05/2015,xyz456,35,bbb
aaa,05/05/2015,xyz456,12,bbb
aaa,06/05/2015,abc123,32,bbb
aaa,06/05/2015,xyz456,43,bbb
aaa,07/05/2015,xyz456,87,bbb
aaa,08/05/2015,abc123,58,bbb
aaa,08/05/2015,xyz456,98,bbb
```

Example: 8th May 2015 Rolling 7 Days data set would be from 08/05/2015 to 02/05/2015

```
aaa,02/05/2015,abc123,25,bbb
aaa,02/05/2015,xyz456,75,bbb
aaa,04/05/2015,abc123,30,bbb
aaa,04/05/2015,xyz456,35,bbb
aaa,05/05/2015,xyz456,12,bbb
aaa,06/05/2015,abc123,32,bbb
aaa,06/05/2015,xyz456,43,bbb
aaa,07/05/2015,xyz456,87,bbb
aaa,08/05/2015,abc123,58,bbb
aaa,08/05/2015,xyz456,98,bbb
```

Output for 8th May 2015 Rolling 7 Days data set

```
RollingDate,Distributor,Amount
08/05/2015,abc123,145
08/05/2015,xyz456,350
```

I am able to obtain the above output from this command :

```
awk -F, '{key=$3;b[key]=b[key]+$4} END {for(i in a) print i","b[i]}'
```

Kindly suggest how to derive weekly split-up data sets then Sum.

Desired Output:

```
RollingDate,Distributor,Amount
01/05/2015,abc123,450
01/05/2015,xyz456,250
02/05/2015,abc123,450
02/05/2015,xyz456,250
03/05/2015,abc123,450
03/05/2015,xyz456,200
04/05/2015,abc123,130
04/05/2015,xyz456,235
05/05/2015,abc123,130
05/05/2015,xyz456,247
06/05/2015,abc123,162
06/05/2015,xyz456,240
07/05/2015,abc123,137
07/05/2015,xyz456,327
08/05/2015,abc123,145
08/05/2015,xyz456,350
```

**Edit#1**

1.

The logic is to find a Sum of Amount is billed to the distributor for the period of 7days range, i.e  if i need to calculate sum for 1st May then I need to consider the line items from 1st May,30th Apr,29th Apr,28th Apr,27th Apr,26th Apr and 25th Apr , It is equivalent to `1st May (-) minus 6 days back` ... like wise 2nd May rolling date is equal to from 2nd May to 26th May ( `2nd May minus 6 days back` ..)

2.

Date format is `DD/MM/YYYY` - 02/05/2015 is 2nd May

3. Since the file contains 2 to 3 months deatils , dont want to select the first date (25/04/2015) from file then do minus 6 days back analysis , hence `"RollingStartDate"` will help from which dates need to consider the data , `"RollingInterval"` will help to do the analysis for "7 days" moving back or "14 days" moving back or "30 days monthly " moving back analysis.
   `"RollingEndDate"` will help to avoid if actual file contains any future date data availabe , in this case if 09th or 15th may date line items need to be excluded ...

Comment: I don't understand how you get the date on your output with your exemple script, it should be only Distributor and amount ...

Comment: @Tensibai, yes you are right, I just put that Rolling_Date logic to understand the requirement correctly ...

Comment: So it's not the actual output you get, that makes hard to understand what you're actually getting and what you're wishing to get at all...

Comment: By the way, is awk mandatory ? (sounds like it's not the perfect tool for this), but that could be done with a multidimensionnal array (date/distributor as key, and then sum it) with some pain

Comment: @Tensibai, awk is not mandatory , but i dont have access for Python & Perl

Comment: I may try to write an answer tomorrow. I'm out of time for today.

Comment: @EdMorton, I have updated under " Edit#1" , please let me know if still is not clear , sorry for poor details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that just excludes dates that don't have 7 days before them instead of requiring a specific start/stop range:

```
$ cat tst.awk        
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; window=(window?window:7); secsPerDay=24*60*60 }
NR==1 { print "RollingDate", $3, $4; next }
{
    endSecs = mktime(gensub(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/,"\\3 \\2 \\1 0 0 0","",$2))
    if (begSecs=="") {
        begSecs = endSecs + ((window-1) * secsPerDay)
    }
    amount[endSecs][$3] += $4
    dists[$3]
}
END {
    for (currSecs=begSecs; currSecs<=endSecs; currSecs+=secsPerDay) {
        for (dayNr=1; dayNr<=window; dayNr++) {
            rollSecs = currSecs - ((dayNr-1) * secsPerDay)
            for (dist in dists) {
                sum[dist] += (rollSecs in amount ? amount[rollSecs][dist] : 0)
            }
        }
        for (dist in dists) {
            print strftime("%d/%m/%Y",currSecs), dist, sum[dist]
            delete sum[dist]
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
RollingDate,Distributor,Amount          
01/05/2015,xyz456,250
01/05/2015,abc123,450
02/05/2015,xyz456,250
02/05/2015,abc123,450
03/05/2015,xyz456,200
03/05/2015,abc123,450
04/05/2015,xyz456,235
04/05/2015,abc123,130
05/05/2015,xyz456,247
05/05/2015,abc123,130
06/05/2015,xyz456,240
06/05/2015,abc123,162
07/05/2015,xyz456,327
07/05/2015,abc123,137
08/05/2015,xyz456,350
08/05/2015,abc123,145
```

.

To use some different window size than 7 days, just set it on the command line:

```
$ awk -v window=5 -f tst.awk file
RollingDate,Distributor,Amount
29/04/2015,xyz456,175
29/04/2015,abc123,375
30/04/2015,xyz456,100
30/04/2015,abc123,375
01/05/2015,xyz456,125
01/05/2015,abc123,425
02/05/2015,xyz456,200
02/05/2015,abc123,100
03/05/2015,xyz456,200
03/05/2015,abc123,100
04/05/2015,xyz456,185
04/05/2015,abc123,130
05/05/2015,xyz456,197
05/05/2015,abc123,105
06/05/2015,xyz456,165
06/05/2015,abc123,87
07/05/2015,xyz456,177
07/05/2015,abc123,62
08/05/2015,xyz456,275
08/05/2015,abc123,120
```

The above uses GNU awk for true 2D arrays and time functions. Hopefully it's clear enough that you can make any modifications you need to include/exclude specific date ranges.

Comment: EdMorton,Thanks a ton, Awesome script, It is working the way it expected, Genius Man !!! Accepted and Up-Voted the answer !!!